# Geometric mean using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate the geometric mean using `dplyr`. I am using some stock tickers and dividend payments. I am trying to `group_by()` each stock symbol and take the last `dividend` value (for example `F` - Ford) in 2018 (0.45000) divide this by the first `dividend` value in 1990 (4.71300) raised to the power of 1/(#of years) then subtract by 1.

`(0.450 / 4.713)^(1/28) - 1` for Ford company with ticker F.

I am getting a little stuck with coding the first and last years etc. since the number of years vary for different firms.

Data:

```
divs_yearly <- structure(list(symbol = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", 
"GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", 
"GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", 
"MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
"MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT"
), year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 
1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 
1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018), dividends = c(4.713, 3.06345, 
2.5136, 2.5136, 2.09682, 1.22994, 1.59787, 1.64484, 1.71978, 
1.88002, 1.80015, 1.05, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.25, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.45, 1.9176, 2.0796, 2.3172, 2.6052, 1.8474, 
1.6896, 1.9008, 1.3404, 1.2501, 1.4604, 0.8435, 0.66, 0.73, 0.77, 
0.82, 0.91, 1.03, 1.15, 1.24, 0.61, 0.46, 0.61, 0.755, 0.79, 
0.89, 0.92, 0.93, 1.2, 0.24, 0.24, 0.16, 0.32, 0.37, 0.41, 0.46, 
0.52, 0.55, 0.68, 0.83, 0.97, 1.15, 1.29, 1.47, 1.59, 1.26), 
    growth = structure(list(symbol = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
    "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
    "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", 
    "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", 
    "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", 
    "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
    "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
    "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT"), year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 
    1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 
    2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
    2018, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 
    1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
    2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
    2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
    2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018), dividends = c(NA, -0.35, 
    -0.17948717948718, 0, -0.165809993634628, -0.413426045154091, 
    0.299144673723921, 0.0293953826030904, 0.045560662435252, 
    0.093174708392934, -0.0424835906001001, -0.416715273727189, 
    -0.619047619047619, 0, 0, 0, -0.375, -0.2, 1, 0.25, 0.2, 
    0, 0, -0.25, NA, 0.0844806007509387, 0.114252740911714, 0.124287933713102, 
    -0.290879778903731, -0.085417343293277, 0.125, -0.294823232323232, 
    -0.0673679498657117, 0.16822654187665, -0.422418515475212, 
    -0.217545939537641, 0.106060606060606, 0.0547945205479452, 
    0.0649350649350651, 0.109756097560975, 0.131868131868132, 
    0.116504854368932, 0.0782608695652172, -0.508064516129032, 
    -0.245901639344262, 0.326086956521739, 0.237704918032787, 
    0.0463576158940397, 0.126582278481013, 0.0337078651685394, 
    0.0108695652173914, 0.290322580645161, -0.8, NA, -0.333333333333333, 
    1, 0.15625, 0.108108108108108, 0.121951219512195, 0.130434782608696, 
    0.0576923076923077, 0.236363636363636, 0.220588235294118, 
    0.168674698795181, 0.185567010309278, 0.121739130434783, 
    0.13953488372093, 0.0816326530612246, -0.207547169811321)), .Names = c("symbol", 
    "year", "dividends"), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -69L), vars = "symbol", labels = structure(list(
        symbol = c("F", "GE", "MSFT")), row.names = c(NA, -3L
    ), class = "data.frame", vars = "symbol", drop = TRUE, .Names = "symbol"), indices = list(
        0:23, 24:52, 53:68), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(24L, 
    29L, 16L), biggest_group_size = 29L)), .Names = c("symbol", 
"year", "dividends", "growth"), row.names = c(NA, -69L), vars = "symbol", drop = TRUE, class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: didn't read all the details, but does it help to know that the geometric mean is equal to the mean computed on the log scale, and then backtransformed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of the last and first functions will get you there. I only took the first 3 columns of your data.set as I got an error trying to use your complete set.

```
divs_yearly %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>% 
  summarise(gm = (last(dividends) / first(dividends)) ^(1 / (last(year) - first(year))) - 1  )

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  symbol      gm
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 F      -0.0805
2 GE     -0.0715
3 MSFT    0.117
```

data:

```
divs_yearly <- structure(list(symbol = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", 
"GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", 
"GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", "GE", 
"MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
"MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT"
), year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 
1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 
1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018), dividends = c(4.713, 3.06345, 
2.5136, 2.5136, 2.09682, 1.22994, 1.59787, 1.64484, 1.71978, 
1.88002, 1.80015, 1.05, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.25, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.45, 1.9176, 2.0796, 2.3172, 2.6052, 1.8474, 
1.6896, 1.9008, 1.3404, 1.2501, 1.4604, 0.8435, 0.66, 0.73, 0.77, 
0.82, 0.91, 1.03, 1.15, 1.24, 0.61, 0.46, 0.61, 0.755, 0.79, 
0.89, 0.92, 0.93, 1.2, 0.24, 0.24, 0.16, 0.32, 0.37, 0.41, 0.46, 
0.52, 0.55, 0.68, 0.83, 0.97, 1.15, 1.29, 1.47, 1.59, 1.26)), row.names = c(NA, 
-69L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```